# Liferay DDMStructure primaryKey is unique?

Tags: java, liferay, primary-key

I have been working on updating a `DDMStructure` from another liferay server application. But I need to have a unique value apart from the id of the DDMStructure inorder to update from the remote application.

I came across the `getPrimaryKey()` method of `DDMStructureModel` which provides the `primaryKey` of the corresponding `DDMStructure`. I want to confirm if this `primaryKey` acts like the primaryKey in Databases. That is, I want to confirm if this primaryKey is unique for `DDMStructure`s within that application.

To illustrate, suppose I have a liferay application running, and I have 2 DDMStructures - D1,D2 . Can D1 and D2 have the **same primaryKey value**? If yes, then what other attribute can I use instead of primaryKey to distinguish them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DDMStructure.getPrimaryKey()` is mapped to `DDMSTRUCTURE.STRUCTUREID` column, which is indeed the primary key (ie. unique).

I don't understand your use case clearly. If you're going to modify the database directly, I would strongly suggest not to. It is usually more reasonable to use Liferay API instead (you might want to check `DDMStructureService`).

[image: DDMSTRUCTURE table]

Comment: Yeah.. in fact I am going to use `updateStructure` method of `DDMStructureService`.. thanks for the information anyways!